# Which is a more preferential approach to validating a .NET Core Web API controller method param: return a BadRequestResult or throw an Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Some additional context - say I have a .NET Core 3.1 Controller class that looks like this, with a GET method `DoStuff()` that calls `SomeClass.FooBar()` to fetch some data:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ObjectResult DoStuff(int baz)
{
    return Ok(SomeClass.FooBar(baz));
}
```

If I wanted to validate that input parameter `baz` is within some range, would it be better to return a `BadRequestResult` like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ObjectResult DoStuff(int baz)
{
    if (baz >= 100) 
    {
       return BadRequest($"Parameter {nameof(baz)} must be less than 100.");
    }

    return Ok(SomeClass.FooBar(baz));
}
```

...or would it be better to throw an Exception and let my custom ErrorController class (implemented as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) handle returning the response to the user like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ObjectResult DoStuff(int baz)
{
    if (baz >= 100) 
    {
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException({nameof(baz)}, "Must be less than 100.");
    }

    return Ok(SomeClass.FooBar(baz));
}
```

...or are neither of these approaches a best practice?

Comment: Which approach most effectively meets your specific software's functional and non-functional requirements?

Comment: I would suspect if it fails validation on the API side, a bad request error would be the more correct way (and you can have your error middleware handle it to properly inform the user what the issue is). The 4xx class of error codes are for when a client sends data over that is incorrect. Per w3.org "The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client seems to have erred...."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Either approach would meet the requirements as the user is returned an HTTP response with a status code of 400 and a message indicating their input parameter is not valid.  I'm looking for the .NET best practice (if there is one) in this situation.

Comment: @matt.f.c use centralised exceptional handler as your logic to handle error will be placed in one location.

Comment: @SomeStudent This was the direction I'm leaning as well - validate the Controller method params and return the BadRequestResult if they are not valid.  If there is an Exception thrown further down the call stack, then I'm thinking it's more appropriate to let the ErrorController class handle the response to the user.

Comment: @CoderSam Thanks for the comment, I do see the benefit of having a centralized location in which all error responses will be handled.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer what you mean by ["best practice?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing)

Comment: [See also.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351356/if-there-are-two-ways-of-approaching-a-task-how-should-one-choose-between-them)

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the context of my question, "best practice" would mean "what does Microsoft recommend" as opposed to a more opinion-based answer.  I was not able to make a definitive determination after reading through the .NET documentation.

Comment: [This Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+.net+core+web+api+validation+example) yields several useful code examples and recommendations from Microsoft.  None of them advocate throwing exceptions.  [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) seems particularly useful.